# Do not log colors to screen logfile?

Tags: logging, gnu-screen, formatting

Running an application inside screen to log all output including stacktraces not caught by the applications logging. Screen is however logging all formatting like `^[[58;1H^[[58;1H` which results in logfile being difficult to read and much larger than necessary.

I tried piping the logfiles through to remove the color and text formatting, but that ends up being quite complex and does not work flawlessly either with a tendency to mess up formatting completely.

Is there an option I can put into screenrc to have screen not log these color and formatting codes and only log plaintext while not discoloring the application output in the screen session itself?

Comment: Is there an option for your app to not generate colors?

Comment: There is, but the colors are used to show errors and warnings, which is pretty useful for debugging, so ideally I want to keep that.